# Eliminate special characters from CSV with C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, csv, encoding, asp.net-web-api

I am getting data from a CSV file through my Web Api with this code

```
private List<Item> items = new List<Item>();

        public ItemRepository()
        {
            string filename = HttpRuntime.AppDomainAppPath + "App_Data\\items.csv";

            var lines = File.ReadAllLines(filename).Skip(1).ToList();

            for (int i = 0; i < lines.Count; i++)
            {
                var line = lines[i];

                var columns = line.Split('$');

                //get rid of newline characters in the middle of data lines
                while (columns.Length < 9)
                {
                    i += 1;
                    line = line.Replace("\n", " ") + lines[i];
                    columns = line.Split('$');
                }

                //Remove Starting and Trailing open quotes from fields
                columns = columns.Select(c => { if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(c) == false) { return c.Substring(1, c.Length - 2); } return string.Empty; }).ToArray();


                var temp = columns[5].Split('|', '>');
                items.Add(new Item()
                {
                    Id = int.Parse(columns[0]),
                    Name = temp[0],
                    Description = columns[2],

                    Photo = columns[7]



                });
            }
        }
```

But the CSV file returned data with special characters instead of an apostrophe.

For example in the CSV file  the are values such as There`&#8217;`s which should be "There's" or "John`&#8217;`s" which should be "John's".
This `&#8217;` is there instead of an apostrophe.

How do I get rid of this to just show my apostrophe. 
This kind of data is being returned in 
 `Name = temp[0],`
`Description = columns[2],`

Comment: Can you try System.Net.WebUtility.HtmlDecode? I'm not sure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the HttpUtility.HtmlDecode to convert the characters.  Here's an example:

```
var withEncodedChars = "For example in the CSV file the are values such as There&#8217;s which should be There's or John&#8217;s which should be John's. This &#8217; is there instead of an apostrophe.";

Console.WriteLine(HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(withEncodedChars));
```

If you run this in a console app it outputs:

> For example in the CSV file the are values such as There's which should be There's or John's which should be John's. This ' is there instead of an apostrophe.